# Powershel Get Elevated process ExitCode

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install an application silently but I could not get the proper exit code since I am running elevated privilege.

Note $Credetial trying to install with another local user with admin privilages.

```
$tab = "C:\Tab Server"
$tab = "D:\TabInstaller\TabServer-64bit.exe"
$tablog = "C:\Temp\Tableaulog\TabInstaller.log"

$list = "-noprofile -command ""Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c ""$tab"" /silent /install ACCEPTEULA=1 ACTIVATIONSERVICE=0 """"""INSTALLDIR=$($drive)"""""" ""/log $tablog""'"""

[int]$result = (Start-Process "powershell.exe" -Credential $credential -ArgumentList $list -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

I tried to get the exit code by trying to pass echo %ERROLEVEL% in the command prompt but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `-Wait` and `-PassThru` combined with `.ExitCode` in the *outer* `Start-Process` call, but you must also apply it to the *inner* one, so as to make the outer call *relay* the inner's exit code, via an `exit` statement:

```
$list = "-noprofile -command ""exit (Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs cmd.exe  -ArgumentList '/c ""$tab"" /silent /install ACCEPTEULA=1 ACTIVATIONSERVICE=0 """"""INSTALLDIR=$($drive)"""""" ""/log $tablog""'").ExitCode"""
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Alex; my pleasure. Thanks for spotting the typo - I've updated the answer.